# Serializing and submitting a form using an AJAX call in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm having trouble serializing a form within my MVC.net application using an Ajax call that is defined as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SpecialNotice", "Displays", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
```

The form is defined as follows and is to be posted to the following controller:

```
public ActionResult SpecialNotice(string dType, bool? immediate,SpecialNoticeModel mod)
```

When I use `$(formid).submit()` everything works fine, the form is passed to the controller and the SpecialNoticeModel is populated with all the correct information that has been defined in the form.

However what I want to do is an AJAX request instead, because I do not want the form to refresh upon submission. The Ajax call I am using is:

```
        var formdata = $('#form').serialize();

    $.post(window.baseUrl + 'Displays/SpecialNotice', { dType: $(displayid).val(), immediate: false, data: formdata }, function () {
        var device = $('#DeviceType').val();
        var postnow = '@Model.PostNow.ToString()';
        window.location.href = window.baseUrl + 'Displays/SpecialNotice?immediate=' + postnow + '&dtype=' + device;
    });
```

The problem I am getting is that the form is not being serialized in the way that the default submit is doing it, the the value of `mod` when passed to the controller is just blank default values. I have also tried renaming data in the ajax call to mod but this didn't work either.

Is there a way to serialize the form manually in a way that `$(formid).submit()` seems to do?

Comment: Make sure all controls have a name attribute. See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: So all elements in the form should have a name that corresponds to the class that they will be serialized to? If that is the case why does .submit() have no problems serializing it into the object without the names added?

Comment: I'm not sure,but same thing specified in  jquery api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER - The problem was after serializing the form I was wrapping it in a json object which was causing problems. Instead I did this and it worked fine:

```
$.post(window.baseUrl + 'Displays/SpecialNotice', formdata, function () {
        var device = $('#DeviceType').val();
        var postnow = '@Model.PostNow.ToString()';
        window.location.href = window.baseUrl + 'Displays/SpecialNotice?immediate=' + postnow + '&dtype=' + device;
    });
```